# Session gets time out frequently although i set timeout time in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

Session gets time out frequently although i set timout time in web.config

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that your ASP.NET worker process isn't being recycled.  If this gets recycled, your sessions are toast.  Check the server's event log for details.

Comment: Yes, especially if it's a development Visual Studio Website Project (where it recompiles when new code is dropped into it) and if anybody is updating the website dynamic pages or code, it will be recycled when modifications are made.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see your timeout, please print `Session.Timeout` to the aspx page and see whether the timeout has changed or not.

```
The session timeout is <%=Session.Timeout%>.
```

should do the job.

Of course you may also set the `Session.Timeout` property in your `global.asax` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **[`Session.Timeout` value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473.aspx) isn't being set differently** somewhere in the code base. Do a global find across your solution for the property.

Check if your [`Session.SessionId` property value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524326.aspx) actually changes by printing it out on the pages you are using, or by inspecting it with debugging tools.  If it is changing early then you'll know for sure, otherwise **maybe some rogue code is just clearing out session variables** and it appears as if the session is timing out.

Beyond this, user bilb has covered the working process information and I left a [comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438582/session-gets-time-out-frequently-although-i-set-timout-time-in-web-config/2438590#2438590) about why I think that might happen, rather than repeating it here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is your session and not the Forms Authentication cookie that is timing out? They are not related.

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30"  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with a very big project that I was working on so recently , the session gets timed out before the specified time, I tried all tricks but none worked till I figured out that why not adding a Timer to the page that post back every once in a while to keep the session alive and it worked , so here is the deal:

1) place a timer in your asp.net page (but the Timer must be placed inside an Update panel so that it doesnt messes up the page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlControls" runat="server">
<asp:Timer ID="tmrLive" runat="server" OnTick="tmrLive_Tick" Interval="50000"></asp:Timer>
</asp:updatePanel>
```

2) in the trmLive_Tick event , simply dont write anything or write a non effective sentence if you want

and thats it (hope it'll help you as it was a real success for me)